# Set my own syntax in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Sometimes I use Sublime Text for writing reminders. 
I always use the same layout for this task which looks like this :

```
>Title
>>Subtitle
>>>Comment

> Title
>> ...
```

Where a `>` represent a tab character

So I'm wondering if it's possible to create my own syntax highlighting for this kinds of files, with one color for the title, another one for the subtitle and the regular color for the comment.

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is performed using `.tmLanguage` [syntax definitions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html). They are formatted in Apple's XML-based PLIST format, although thanks to the excellent Sublime plugin [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) they can be written in JSON or in YAML, which I chose for its compactness, and the fact that I get sweet syntax highlighting with it using my theme<sup>*</sup>.

So, your syntax is very straightforward. You'll have three rules:

1. Matching lines beginning with a single tab as "Title" lines
2. Matching lines beginning with two tabs as "Subtitle" lines
3. Matching lines beginning with three tabs as "Comment" lines.

Everything else will be displayed by Sublime as plain text.

---

Here it is, in YAML:

```yaml
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
---
name: Reminders
comment: Written for http://stackoverflow.com/q/25689365/1426065 by @MattDMo
scopeName: text.reminders
fileTypes: [todo]
uuid: 6B548E74-5E01-497A-B030-9D31131B7A70

patterns:
- name: text.title.reminders
  match: ^\t(?!\t+)(.*)

- name: text.subtitle.reminders
  match: ^\t\t(?!\t+)(.*)

- name: text.comment.reminders
  match: ^\t\t\t(.*)
```

Everything is pretty straightforward. The name is what shows up in the bottom right corner of Sublime, it was written by me, its base scope name is `text.reminders`, opening a file with the `.todo` extension will automatically apply this syntax, and the UUID is just a unique identifier. As I mentioned above, there are three patterns. One thing to keep in mind: **this will only match if the line begins with a literal tab character, not space characters being inserted as a tab!** That means you'll need to select 
**`View -> Indentation`** and make sure **`Indent Using Spaces`** is **NOT** checked. Just for good measure, select **`View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation to Tabs`** as well. These settings can be applied just to "Reminders" views, I'll cover that later.

---

So we have our YAML, which is useless if you don't have `PackageDev`. However, translated to a PLIST it works much better:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>Written for http://stackoverflow.com/q/25689365/1426065 by @MattDMo</string>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>todo</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Reminders</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>^\t(?!\t+)(.*)</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>text.title.reminders</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>^\t\t(?!\t+)(.*)</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>text.subtitle.reminders</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>^\t\t\t(.*)</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>text.comment.reminders</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>text.reminders</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>6B548E74-5E01-497A-B030-9D31131B7A70</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In Sublime, create a new file with XML syntax and copy the above XML into it. Find your `Packages` directory by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** then save this new file as `Packages/User/Reminders.tmLanguage` (make sure the `L` in `tmLanguage` is capitalized). There should now be a "Users -> Reminders" option in the language list in the bottom right of Sublime, or through the **`View -> Syntax`** menu option.

---

However, there's one more thing to do - get coloring. To do this you'll need to modify your `.tmTheme` color scheme file. Since you're using Sublime Text 2 (I assume), it's pretty easy. Open **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and check the value of `"color_scheme"`. Open the color scheme file by selecting **`File -> Open...`**, navigating to the `Packages` directory you found earlier with **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**, and opening the file in whatever subdirectory it's in. For example, if your settings file says `"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"` you'll navigate to the `Packages/Color Scheme - Default` directory in the open file dialog and open `Monokai.tmTheme`. Super easy.

Now that you have your color scheme file open, you can set the syntax to XML if you want, then scroll all the way down to the bottom. You'll want to insert your new colors (I'll get to that in a minute) **above** the lines that say:

```xml
    </array>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>06CD1FB2-A00A-4F8C-97B2-60E131912345</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The UUID may not even be there, it might just say:

```xml
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Regardless, whichever is there **should always be the last lines in the file, or things will break**. At any rate, above these lines, insert the following dicts:

```xml
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Reminders - Title</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.reminders text.title.reminders</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>bold italic</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#00FF00</string>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Reminders - Subtitle</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.reminders text.subtitle.reminders</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FF0080</string>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Reminders - Comment</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.reminders text.comment.reminders</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>background</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Feel free to customize the `foreground` and `background` colors and the `fontStyle` attributes ("*bold*" and "*italic*" are the only working values) however you like.

---

One more thing, if you'll remember - setting Sublime to use tabs just in *Reminders* views. Create a new file using JSON syntax, or if you installed `PackageDev`, with "Sublime Settings" syntax. Add to it the following:

```js
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "extensions": 
    [
        "todo"
    ]
}
```

(Yes, I know "todo" is already in the language definition, I just like to be safe). You can add any other option here that's used in the **`Preferences -> Settings-Default`** and **`... -> Settings-User`** files, just make sure the file is valid [JSON](http://json.org). Save the file as `Packages/User/Reminders.sublime-settings`.

---

And that's it! You may need to restart Sublime for the changes to kick in, but then you're all set. To recap, the steps to making a new syntax definition are as follows:

1. Get [`PackageDev`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageDev), your life will be a lot easier.
2. Write highlighting regexes in JSON or YAML format using the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) regex language, testing online with tools like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) (using Ruby 1.9.2 option).
3. Compile to PLIST/XML.
4. Modify color scheme for new scopes.
5. Create a `.sublime-settings` file for syntax-specific settings like tabs.
6. ???
7. Profit!

---

<sup>* linked in my user profile if you're interested...</sup>

Comment: this has been phenomenally helpful -- if you could take a look at a similar question I recently asked, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: @MattDMo so doing this will add some color to that specific file only? OP mentioned using tabs, is there a way to set it so if a sentence starts with a character(s), like # or //, it'll change colors?

Comment: @vytfla yes, all you'll have to do is adjust the regexes to match `#` or `//` or whatever you want.

Comment: @MattDMo Okay, thanks. So I believe I added everything correctly. How does everything I just did know that I want to associate it with a current file? I tried tabbing in my file but it's not working. Also, I'm not familiar with regex, how would I customize it for those characters I want?